# Interaction Picture Propagator

Tags: perturbation-theory

From Page.81 of Peskin and Schroeder

> ... we note that $U(t,t_0)$ is the unique solution, with initial condition $U(t_0,t_0) = 1$, of
> a simple differential equation(the Schrodinger equation):

> $ i \frac{\partial}{\partial t} U(t,t_0) = e^{iH_0(t-t_0)}(H-H_0)e^{-iH(t-t_0)}....$

How did the textbook arrive at this?

I have used the Heisenberg equation of motion:

> $i \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathscr{O} = [\mathscr{O},\mathscr{H}]$

and arrived at the following point and am stuck:

> $i \frac{\partial}{\partial t} U(t,t_0) = [e^{iH_0(t-t_0)},H].e^{-iH(t-t_0)}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beforehand the author defined the unitary operator
$$
U(t,t_0) = \text{e}^{iH_0(t-t_0)}\text{e}^{-iH(t-t_0)}
$$
Hence we arrive at
$$
i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}U(t,t_0) = \text{e}^{iH_0(t-t_0)}(H - H_0)\text{e}^{-iH(t-t_0)}
$$
by differentiation of $U(t, t_0)$ using the product and the chain rule. Actually the author "derives" the Schrödinger equation for the operator $U(t,t_0)$.